# How to convert m-files to dlls?

Tags: .net, matlab, converters

How can I convert a matlab m-file to a .net assembly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Matlab Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/) to compile .m files into .NET assemblies.

For other possibilities of interfacing .NET from MATLAB, see [MATLAB Interface to .NET Framework](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/brpb5k6.html)

PS: Google's your friend...

Comment: sorry that I'm not native english and that I do not really have the time to work on my grammar. What I tried to say with my last sentence is that I've no experience at all with MATLAB, all I did was to enter "MATLAB M File .NET assembly" in google and I got the two links mentioned in my answer ;-) ...

Answer (score 0):

don't know if its what you need, but you can check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked this but I think you can generate C code using the mcc command but don't trust me on that!

type `help mcc` for more details about the compiler documentation

Comment: It was true with older MATLAB versions, with R14 `mcc` does not compile into machine code but unto "MATLAB intermediate language" so that you still need MATLAB Component Runtime to run it.